# Login Failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\xxx'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:18456)

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm asking this question the nth time. That is because I didn't still came up with a solution from all the solutions out there.

My error log reads this:-

```
2018-06-02 18:32:54.02 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2018-06-02 18:32:54.02 Logon       Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\deepak_ditm@rediffmail.com'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

My problem is that I don't know where to find this login ID and how to change it.

PS: Already googled a lot. Nothing helpful found. :(

Comment: Logins can be found in `sys.syslogins`. Considering that the Login doesn't exist, you don't need to change an existing one, you need to create one: [CREATE LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&tabs=sqlserver)

Comment: Thanks for reply @Larnu. As this is the first time I've opened sql sever 2017 after installation, I cannot access any database (and thus can't execute sys.syslogins). Is there any other way for doing this?

Comment: When you installed SQL Server, you were asked which accounts would need to have system admin priviledge and/or set the password for tha `sa` account. Log in as the `sa` or one of the accounts you gave syadmin privs too during the installation. You'll then be able to use `CREATE LOGIN`.

Comment: Ok. It asked for system admin priviledges . Don't remember the set password.

Comment: /facepalm /headdesk

Comment: [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-2017). And I then suggest learning about SQL Server first before using it any further.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that.